# How to Automate SAP Fiori Using Selenium (JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sap-fiori

I want to know how to automate SAP Fiori (Browser) using Selenium in Java?

Did I need to install some external tools or need to enable some SAP configuration in order to read the element inside Fiori interface?

I already tried to read Fiori element but the selenium keep on telling that the element cannot be found.

*Thanks for your kind respond guys I try with Xpath that include (contains) it seems working but with normal get by.id/class/tag it seems some value cannot be read by Selenium. Just one thing I'm not sure, did HTTP / HTTPS affect the Selenium detection?*

Comment: please share the html code?

Comment: Relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace please

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty generic.
It should be possible, to use Selenium for testing UI5 apps.
[Here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/0976bc2b589741dcb54ff491a8ddc75b) it says that you need to install additional Selenium web drivers.

You might also want to check out OPA5, as described under [Testing](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/7cdee404cac441888539ed7bfe076e57) 
and under [Integration Testing with One Page Acceptance Tests (OPA5)](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/2696ab50faad458f9b4027ec2f9b884d.html).

[This blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/10/16/javascript-based-integration-tests-for-sapui5-apps-with-opa/) compares Selenium and OPA5.

This thread [Automated UI tests for SAP UI5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934012/automated-ui-tests-for-sap-ui5) might also be helpful.